# how to implement SSO with saml in my project using spring core not spring boot?

Tags: java, spring

we would like to use OKTA as service authentication and authorisation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please write what have you tried

Comment: What is stopping you? Are you looking for documentation? have you looked at https://developer.okta.com/code/java/spring_security_saml ?

Comment: Thanks @SheetalMohanSharma, I have gone through the documentation and try to configure locally, the thing is that the example is migrated to the spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Just use https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

You do not need Spring Boot to use Spring Security SAML